# About the Large Hadron Collider

Tags: experimental-physics

I think Physics is fascinating , especially those really clever experiments one can do that demonstrate some important principle and probably don't cost a lot of money to make. Also the Thought Experiments of Galileo and Einstein and Maxwell (I think) and many others ; thought experiments that cost nothing and point out interesting ideas and possibly how to design real experiments to verify some of these ideas. Note Einstein's thought experiment about imagining himself riding a beam of light and putting a mirror in front of him , would he see his reflection? This thought experiment helped him formulate Relativity Theory. It's great when some BRILLIANT scientist figures out a relatively inexpensive way to test some complicated idea. CAN EXPENSIVE EXPERIMENTS be redesigned so they are inexpensive yet still effective?

Answer (score 13):

My answer to this is that the LHC costs were of the same order of magnitude as one [aircraft carrier.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimitz-class_aircraft_carrier)

> The total cost of construction for each ship was around $4.5 billion

Of which several are around

The [cost of the LHC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Hadron_Collider) was

> With a budget of 7.5 billion euros (approx. $9bn or £6.19bn as of June 2010),

So we have one country, the US spending same order of magnitude for boats that may end up at the bottom of the ocean , all costs lost.  LHC is built by a collaboration of many countries, order of 11, where the US has contributed order of 0.5 billion dollars, and a lot of the infrastructure is recoverable  and reusable once its time is past  . Look how the old infrastructure has been used for the newest accelerators at CERN :

[image: LHC]

All those circles going from the bottom up were each a state of the art frontier accelerator at some point.

There is a reason for building aircraft carriers ( defensive and offensive capabilities) and a reason for building large scientific structures. These latter offer a multitude of benefits to the countries as a whole

a) by advancing knowledge,

at the moment of interest only to physicists but remember at the beginning of the last century nuclear energy was of interest only to physicist ( and innumerable other examples)

b) by developing unprecedented technology that then goes back to the public community:

the very [web page we are communicating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web) right now was developed at CERN for the needs of experiments with the previous accelerator , LEP.

There are many examples of the transfer of  High Energy Physics technology to the general public use that would never have appeared if it were not for the great technological demands of experiments.

You say :

> thought experiments that cost nothing and point out interesting ideas. It's great when some scientist figures out a relatively inexpensive way to test some complicated idea

Thought experiments are science fiction if not verified by data.  The energies necessary to verify the current thought experiments of theorists are very large and require thousands of competent scientists to work on the experiments,after the accelerator is completed ( Atlas and CMS experiments have 3000 physicists each). The expenses come from grants and from the various institutes in the countries who support the research. By the way, the need for enormous data handling at the LHC has pushed the world's  data handling methods to new peaks, which is an advantage for all people, even the men in the street.

So, to recapitulate, the cost of the collider  and its experiments is carried by many countries and is comparable to military hardware of just one country in price. It is a collective endeavor that will bear real fruit maybe in a century, which is what happened with the electromagnetic theory which was just an interesting problem for physicists when developed. I will remind you that *"not by bread alone"* is still valid. Humanity needs intellectual goals to progress.

*Edit after edit of the question*

> Can expensive experiments be redesigned so they are inexpensive yet still effective?

The short answer is NO. It would have been done if it could have been done. All those thousands of PhDs are not idiots.

It is true that new methods of acceleration might be devised, given the new technologies available, [like nanotechnology](http://www.nanowerk.com/news2/newsid=32647.php), but it will require many years of research and development to reach the point of giving the same energies and luminosities  as conventional accelerators, if ever.